# How Can I put a box around text and allow user to scroll using scrollbar only on the paragrah using css and div tag

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create a profile page using[image] html and css. I want to put each individual paragraph in a scroll bar like box so I can then resize relative to the page. I tried using a div tag and background color to make box clear but I am unable to see a box or scrollbar. I do not want a scrollbar on the page, strictly the paragraph itself.

Comment: PRO TIP: Post your code into your question. Don't screenshot it.

Comment: @TomDickson, Got it thank you

Answer (score 1):

you have to define some height for your div, too.

Comment: I did that but nothing changed, I put height at 40 px

Comment: add overflow-y: scroll

Comment: and fix the id name About-Marquz, the space won't be recognised

Answer (score 0):

Give each paragraph a `max-height` shorter than the text, and a `overflow:scroll` rule:

```css
.scrollPar {
  width: 70%;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollPar">

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</div>

<div class="scrollPar">

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</div>

<div class="scrollPar">

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</div>

<div class="scrollPar">

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the `height` or `max-height` of the content. Here i have set the content height to 30px and set `overflow-y` to scroll (this will add the scroll bar on the right):

```css
.content {
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Heading</h2>
<div class="content">
  <p>Hows it going mate I have a bunch of content here and I am writing a bunch of words that make little to no sense</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `height` and `overflow` property is what you're looking for I guess.
Take a look at the below link :)
https://jsfiddle.net/rwg1e2uo/